# What does "Managed by Windows" do in the Power options for network connection?

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-management

In the power management option for Windows 10 I can configure what happens to my network connection when my PC goes to sleep for power saving:

*When my PC is asleep and on battery power, disconnect from the network*

- *Never*
- *Always*
- *Managed by Windows*

[image: Screenshot of the configuration dialog]

While I can make sense of the first two options, what exactly is the effect of having this being *managed by Windows*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/network-connection-settings) Microsoft Doc:

> Managed by Windows - Only important apps that have been recently used are permitted to maintain access to the network. Apps designated as important are:
>   Any app that the user sets to Allow to run background tasks
>   All VOIP apps

Answer (score 5):

> While I can make sense of the first two options, what exactly is the effect of having this being managed by Windows?

It means only important recently used applications are allowed to maintain access to the network.

[image]

Source: [Network Connection Settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/network-connection-settings)